# Apache LdapNetworkConnection is Null

Tags: ldap, lotus-notes

i have here a strange situation.

I have created the small app, which is connecting to the LDAP Server using the apache LDAP library. I have exported it as jar and it run, the connection was set. It was created and build in Eclipse, JDK 1.6.

I have then created a Java Agent in Lotus Notes, added all libraries, and the connection could not be set.

I have got this error:

```
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message: org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.exception.InvalidConnectionException: Cannot connect on the server, the connection is null
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.checkSession(LdapNetworkConnection.java:270)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindAsync(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1274)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1185)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1043)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
07.08.2015 16:11:36   AMgr: Agent ('TestLDAP' in 'test/tel_sez3.nsf') error message:    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code is very small. The username and password are correct, and the Domino server can see the LDAP server, because i have tested it with running the jar file from direct from the server.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                  new X509TrustManager() {

                      public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                      {
                          return null;
                      }
                      public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                      {
                          //No need to implement.
                      }
                      public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                      {
                          //No need to implement.
                      }
                  }
          };


          LdapConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new
                   LdapConnectionConfig();
                               connectionConfig.setLdapHost("XXX");
                               connectionConfig.setLdapPort(636);
                               connectionConfig.setName("XXX");
                               connectionConfig.setCredentials("XXX");
                               connectionConfig.setUseSsl(true);
                               connectionConfig.setSslProtocol("SSLv3");
                            //   connectionConfig.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts);

                              connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(connectionConfig);


                              connection.bind();
```

I have checked the source of the LDAP Library, and there is method checkSession, where the ldapSession is checked. And this ldapSession is in the bind() method null.

Domino Server: 8.5.3 FP2

Thanx for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're not showing any type of security exception, my first instinct is that that's what you are up against. Domino's Agent Manager enforces security constraints on all agents, and the JVM also enforces it's own constraints. Accesssing the network from an agent requires extra permissions, si let's start at the AMGR level.

Certain operations are considered [restricted](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_RUNNING_RESTRICTED_AGENTS.html). Accessing the network is one of them. There are two points of control for this:

- Specific users must be allowed to sign agents that perform restricted operations. This is done by the system admins, by [setting a field in the Programmability section of the Security tab in Server Document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/othr_serverdocumentsecuritytab_r.dita?lang=en). The field is labeled "Allow unrestricted methods and operations". (If that wording seenms backwards, that's because it is, but it's been that way for about 15 years.)
- Specific agents must be configured to notify the AMGR that they will perform restricted operations. This is done by the developer, by [setting a field on the Security tab of the Agent Properties dalog](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETTING_UP_AGENT_SECURITY_USING_THE_SECURITY_TAB_OVER.html). This is a dropdown field labeled "Restricted Operations" and the value you want is "Allow restricted operations".

The restrictions enforced by the JVM are a much more complex subject, but it's not clear whether they're coming into play or not. Try the above, and see if it works.

If it doesn't, well... they JVM's restrictions can be modified globally by editing the [Java policy file](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21679242), but that's getting into very dangerous territory. Fortunately, the default policy file settings grant AllPermissions to code in jar files that are physically placed in the Domino server's jvm/lib/ext folder. That's on the theory that anyone who can access the server's file system is trusted a great deal more than just some random user with the rights to create agents. But there's to do than just putting the code in that folder. Even though the classes are now loaded from the filesystem, the restrictions that the JVM is placing on the agent's main class are still going to be enforced. To get around this, the agent needs to use java.security.AccessController to switch the running context. The [answer to another question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169014/domino-agent-struggling-with-java-security-using-third-party-jar-in-jvm-lib-ext) points to a blog post that goes through this in a lot of detail.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanx for your long answer: The agent had already the biggest persmission, and the java policy file is now for testing purpose set grant all activities. This was the first things i have set before running it. But maybe this could be a litle bit of topic, how could we set the logging level - sf4j of the third party library to DEBUG level, maybe i can see more detail of the not connection error. Thanx.